# VB.NET Get page Source WebBrowser Control

Tags: vb.net, browser

i want to get the html Source code of website,

it something like:

```
wb.Document...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1:

```
webbrowser1.document.body.innerhtml
```

2:

```
Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
Dim result As String = webClient.DownloadString("http://www.google.co.il")
```

;)